# Sort the array elements based on the date values in the array

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, associative-array

I have an array like

```
Array ( [0] => Luke Karizo => Jul 18 2021 [1] => telse Elarazo => Aug 15 2021 [2] => Sarath S => Jul 08 2021 )
```

I am trying to reorder or sort the elements based on the date values in it. What I have tried is

```
function date_sort($a, $b) {
    return strtotime($a) - strtotime($b);
}
usort($main_Array, "date_sort");
print_r($main_Array);
```

I am expecting a result like

```
Array ( [0] => Sarath S => Jul 08 2021 [1] => Luke Karizo => Jul 18 2021 [2] => telse Elarazo => Aug 15 2021)
```

Is there any way I can sort this array based on the date values? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i am not sure about the array that you are giving, if you could rewrite it properly that would be nice,

but if it is a multidimensional array like i think it is, it should be like :

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [name]     => Luke Karizo,
        [datetime] => Jul 18 2021
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [name]     => Sarath S,
        [datetime] => Jul 08 2021
    )
...
```

and this should do the work :

```
function date_compare($a, $b)
{
    return strtotime($a['datetime']) - strtotime($b['datetime']);
}    
usort($array, 'date_compare');
print_r($array);
```

Comment: Tried this and not getting the result as expected. Please see below `Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [name] => Luke Karizo
            [birth_Day] => 1942/07/18
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [name] => Natelse Elarazo
            [birth_Day] => 1947/08/15
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [name] => Sarath S
            [birth_Day] => 1990/07/08
        )

)`

Comment: Sorry, it's working I forgot to change the year to the current year.